# Asterisk lines busy message repeated endless in a loop

Tags: voip, asterisk, pbx

When someone call to our number I'd like to play a message "All our lines are busy at the moment, please hold on..." some music and then again "All our lines are busy at the moment, please hold on..." and so on ...forever until the caller decide to hangup or the operator take the call.

Is it possible? How do I have to configure Asterisk to make the message loop?

Comment: nice...
I've tried configuring the queues.conf but there is no config options that could make this. Is it maybe something to set in musiconhold.conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something helpful for you here:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+queues.conf

Periodic announcements are available in queues using the new periodic-announce and periodic-announce-frequency options. This allows a message like **"Thank you for holding, your call is important to us."** To be played at regular intervals while a caller is in the queue. e.g:

```
periodic-announce = thank-you-message  
periodic-announce-frequency = 60 ; every 60 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to setup a music on hold class in /etc/asterisk/musiconhold.conf and define it in your queues.conf:
;musicclass = default

other thing you can do is put a normal music on hold for your callers and a play them a periodic announce every x seconds, in the queues.conf: periodic-announce